# Why objective-c object does not refresh after receive a message?

Tags: objective-c, refresh, message

A have an `NSView` object, and it get an message after i push in the Menü bar the Open submenü. It load exchange data from a textfile, and it should render it in a `CustomView`. So the

```
-(IBAction)loadExchangeData:(id)sender
```

load the data, and store in a `NSMutableArray*`, and after it should rendered it by drawRect.

But! In the `drawRect` function the before loaded data disappear, the `NSMutableArray*` will 0X0 again.

And part of the code:

.h:

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
 @interface Chart : NSView 
 {
     NSMutableArray * exchange;
 }
 - (IBAction)loadExchangeData:(id)sender;
 @end
```

.m:

```
#import "Chart.h"
@implementation Chart
- (IBAction)loadExchangeData:(id)sender {
     ...
     exchange = [NSMutableArray array];
     [exchange addObject:...];
     ...
     return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect 
{
    ...
    id sth = [exchange objectAtIndex:i];
    ...
}
@end
```

Comment: Post the code from loadExchangeData: so we can see what might be the cause.

Comment: thanks for the code - did you verified that you are not using 2 different objects of Chart, this kind of issue normally comes if you add data to one object and you try access data from another object. Check address of Chart object when loadExchangeData is executed and when drawRect is executed.
You can keep brake point in both the functions and verify the object address in call stack.

Comment: I checked, yes, this is the problem. Them has different address. How can it happend?

Comment: In the Interface Builder in MainMenu.nib window i have an object instance. This could be the problem? Interface Builder make an own object independent from the original object? But somehow i should denote the connection between submenu and message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your explanation it looks like your referring different objects, your setting to NSMutableArray which is in one object and drarect is referring to a different object.

Debug the code to know the object address which hold the NSMutableArray, this could help you to narrow down the issue.

For further assistance add part of code to know more.

Update based on the code and comment

You might have a object in nib and one created in code, in this case  avoid the creation of  object in code and refer the object created in nib in code using outlet(IBOutlet).